# Stange behavior of header flex element when the screen gets smaller than400px

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK81W.png)Idk what happens to my html page when the screen gets too small the header shrinks and doesn't take the full width of the parent as indicated in the css

here is the css

```
*,
::before,
::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root{
    --text-color:#fff;
}
body,html{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
    user-select: none;

}
header.header{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    background:url(./images/background2.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

    
}
.header .logo .name{
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.header .logo .slogan{
    margin-top:0;
   
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.header .logo {
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-shadow: 1px 2px #1b0101;
}
.main-upload{
    padding-top: 3em;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.header-content{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   
}

.watchlist{
    align-self: flex-end;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin: auto 1em auto auto ;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

form{
    position: absolute;
    align-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 11.5em;
    padding: 0 2em ;

}
form *:not(i){
    padding: 0.8em 1em ;
    border:none;
    border-top: solid 2px  rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: solid 2px  rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
}
form input{
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    flex: 1;
    border-left: solid 2px  rgb(69, 1, 1);
}
form button{
    border-radius: 0 20px   20px 0;
    border-right: solid 2px rgb(69, 1, 1);
    

}

/* Style of films list */
main .films{
    margin: 2em auto 1em ;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    max-width: 700px;
    gap: 1em;


    
}

.film{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E7EB;
    padding:  0.5em ;
}
.info-film{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1em 2em ;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.film .img-container img{
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.film .relevent-info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
   
}
.film .relevent-info .review{
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.film .file-type {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.film .file-type *:not(i){
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.film .file-type button{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: none; 
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.film .file-type button i{
    color: var(--text-color) !important;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;

}
.film .description{
    color: #6B7280;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Movie Seach App</title>
    <!-- Font family links -->
    <!-- Alegria -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:ital,wght@1,400;1,600;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Inter  -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;600;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font awsome kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de0f1ce5ee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 class="name">Explore Movies</h1>
                <p class="slogan">Elevating Your Cinematic Quest to a Premiere Experience</p>
            </div>
            <a href="./watchList.html" class="watchlist" title="watch list"><i class="fa-solid fa-list" ></i> <span>My Watchlist</span></a>

        </div>
       
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
            <button>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <main>
        <!-- <div class="main-upload">
            <img src="./images/film-rolls-animate.svg" alt="triangle with all three sides equal" width="300px"  /> 

        </div> -->
        <div class="films">
            <div class="film">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="./images/runner.png" alt="" class="image-film">
                </div>
                <div class="info-film">
                    <div class="relevent-info">
                        <h3 class="title">Blade Runner</h3>
                        <span class="review"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-star" style="color: #fff700;"></i></span><span>8.1</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-type">
                        <span class="duration">117min</span>
                        <span class="type">Action,Drama</span>
                        <button class="add-watchList">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            Watchlist
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="description">
                        A blade runner must pursue and terminate four replicants who stole a ship in space, and have returned to Earth to find their creator.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="film">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="./images/runner.png" alt="" class="image-film">
                </div>
                <div class="info-film">
                    <div class="relevent-info">
                        <h3 class="title">Blade Runner</h3>
                        <span class="review"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-star" style="color: #fff700;"></i></span><span>8.1</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-type">
                        <span class="duration">117min</span>
                        <span class="type">Action,Drama</span>
                        <button class="add-watchList">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            Watchlist
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="description">
                        A blade runner must pursue and terminate four replicants who stole a ship in space, and have returned to Earth to find their creator.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="film">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="./images/runner.png" alt="" class="image-film">
                </div>
                <div class="info-film">
                    <div class="relevent-info">
                        <h3 class="title">Blade Runner</h3>
                        <span class="review"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-star" style="color: #fff700;"></i></span><span>8.1</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-type">
                        <span class="duration">117min</span>
                        <span class="type">Action,Drama</span>
                        <button class="add-watchList">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            Watchlist
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="description">
                        A blade runner must pursue and terminate four replicants who stole a ship in space, and have returned to Earth to find their creator.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="film">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="./images/runner.png" alt="" class="image-film">
                </div>
                <div class="info-film">
                    <div class="relevent-info">
                        <h3 class="title">Blade Runner</h3>
                        <span class="review"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-star" style="color: #fff700;"></i></span><span>8.1</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-type">
                        <span class="duration">117min</span>
                        <span class="type">Action,Drama</span>
                        <button class="add-watchList">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" style="color: #000000;"></i>

                            Watchlist
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="description">
                        A blade runner must pursue and terminate four replicants who stole a ship in space, and have returned to Earth to find their creator.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="film">
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src="./images/runner.png" alt="" class="image-film">
                </div>
                <div class="info-film">
                    <div class="relevent-info">
                        <h3 class="title">Blade Runner</h3>
                        <span class="review"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-star" style="color: #fff700;"></i></span><span>8.1</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-type">
                        <span class="duration">117min</span>
                        <span class="type">Action,Drama</span>
                        <button class="add-watchList">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                            Watchlist
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="description">
                        A blade runner must pursue and terminate four replicants who stole a ship in space, and have returned to Earth to find their creator.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
            
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with:100% for the child in this case heade rit doesn't work i tried to make the whole body a flex container and give it a flex of 1 but it doesn't work as well

Comment: We don't need the whole page. Please reduce your code to just the **relevant** issue.

Comment: It's not that big that it should be so hard to cleanup, but its been at least an hour and the best result has unfortunately come from deleting all the CSS. Something that may help is using VSCode with a Live Preview plugin: open the page in your browser, open dev tools, focus a specific element in the Computed tab in the right-hand container, then modify that element in CSS. Also read some docs for what you use, e.g. [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size): `contain` crops the image if needed. Nesting flex containers is almost definitely not helping.